# Laravel query results not display on the blade properly

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I'm trying to display some records on my blade.

Following is my Controller function related to this issue.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vrs = SampleRegistration::latest()->where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $trs = TestResult::all()->where('test_id','=',$id);
    //dd($trs);
    return view('viewresults.show',compact('vrs','trs'));
}
```

And I'm trying to display those data on my blade, following is my blade part.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
     @foreach ($trs as  $key => $tr)
         <strong>{{ $tr->test_type }}</strong>
         {{ $tr->test_result }}
     @endforeach    
     </div>
</div>
```

But now the issue is with,

```
$trs = TestResult::all()->where('test_id','=',$id);
```

This can have 1 or more results.

But, even though it has more results, every time this will display only one result on my blade.

And any of the time it won't display the

```
<strong>{{ $tr->test_type }}</strong>
```

But when I `DD` it shows me all the results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this, I just changed my query into this

```
$trs =DB::table('test_results')
            ->where('test_id','=',$id)
            ->get();
```

and now It displays all the records, still have no idea why the previous

```
$trs = TestResult::all()->where('test_id','=',$id);
```

was failing.

Comment: That's basically the same query as @sta recommended, only using QueryBuilder and not Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

user the eloquent queries as ---

```
public function show($id)
{
    $vrs = SampleRegistration::where('id','=',$id)->latest()->first();
    $trs = TestResult::where('test_id','=',$id)->all();
    //dd($trs);
    return view('viewresults.show',compact('vrs','trs'));
}
```

I think rest is fine. Please try it.

Comment: nope, tried this also, but was not working properly then I changed the query, it has worked